# Update markers with current position on Google Map API

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps

I am learning to use javascript right now with Rails and I'm having some issues with updating my markers according to my current position using AJAX. I believe the ready page:load is not running the updated coords that have been attached as a data-attribute, coords since the page is not technically reloading. How can I use my current position data and update it with events with longitude/latitude values?

```
var map; 

$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
 if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    myMap.init();

    var coords = $('#map-canvas').data('coords');

    if (coords){
        myMap.addMarkers(coords);
    }
 }
});

myMap.init = function() {
 if(navigator.geolocation){

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        map: map
    });

    map.setCenter(pos);

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;  

    $.ajax({
        url:"/all_events",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        },
        dataType: 'script'
    });
});

} else {
    document.getElementById('map-canvas').innerHTML = 'No Geolocation Support.';
}

};

myMap.addMarkers = function(coords){

var image = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"

coords.forEach(function(coord){
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude, coord.longitude),
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
});
}
```

Comment: firstly, use bounds_changed event of google map  so that u can get current posistion(viewport) on the map ,and according to that current position bring markers which lies inside that position and then add success event in ajax and inside that event call a function which  will add the markers once again to the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your script work in the way you want please try out the following steps:

- Put your foreach loop in a function and call it at the end of your successive AJAX callbacks.
- Load the AJAX once the Google Maps have finished loading completely. If Google Maps library has not finished loading than you wont be able to create a Google LatLng object, this is what is probably happening over here.

Hope this would help